# Problem copying overriden linked collection from one blend file to another

Tags: collections

Long story short. I have a collection with subcollections in the one blend file and I want to copy those into another blend file. The problem is that those subcollections won't copy (though I try to select everything inside of it).
Any workaround?

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to copy (append?) and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

On your new Blend file, go to File > Append. and then select the other Blend file and select collection.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work in my case because I have linked collection inside of those ones I'm willing to copy, which means I will have to override them once again in the new blend file - but it won't work for me.